# pandas mean values with where condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot

I would like to calculate the mean of age excluding the value 99. In real life the dataframe is much bigger, and I have other possible variables.

Is there a more efficient way (faster or more elegant) to do it?  Maybe with a pivot table or group by, or a function?

```
data = {'age': [99,45,34,32,34,67,5,6,7,8,3,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['age'])

not99 = df['age'] != 99

mean_for_age = df.loc[not99, 'age'].mean()
```

Comment: I think your solution is nice, why do you think `pivot table or group by` is necessary?

Comment: `df[df['age'] != 99]` is probably the best you'll get

Comment: @jezrael I was wandering if in case of large dataframes one option is better than others

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` solution is faster - first create array and then filter:

```
arr = df['age'].values
not99 = arr != 99

mean_for_age = arr[not99].mean()
```

But if need generally solution for possible select another column use your solution:

```
not99 = df['age'] != 99
mean_for_age = df.loc[not99, 'age'].mean()

mean_for_age = df.loc[not99, 'another col'].mean()
```

**Timings** (depends of data, best test with real data):

```
data = {'age': [99,45,34,32,34,67,5,6,7,8,3,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['age'])

df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)


In [14]: %%timeit
    ...: arr = df['age'].values
    ...: not99 = arr != 99
    ...: 
    ...: mean_for_age = arr[not99].mean()
    ...: 
496 µs ± 36.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [15]: %%timeit
    ...: not99 = df['age'] != 99
    ...: mean_for_age = df.loc[not99, 'age'].mean()
    ...: 
1.82 ms ± 40.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [16]: %%timeit
    ...: df.query("age != 99")['age'].mean()
    ...: 
4.26 ms ± 40.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```